# Feedback Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, neuroscience

I'm looking for a Neural Network has feedback weights.
Feedback weights are connections between neurons from a layer to a previous layer. For instance: from the output layer to the input layer. I did many searches on internet, but I found only a paper of Zamir https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09508.pdf
Some websites say that feedback network are recurrent neural network, but according to my knowledge RNN has additional weights for same neurons of the same layer.
Could someone provide me any other information?